# Find the optimal, width, height, and total area

Tags: calculus, derivatives

If I was trying to design a printed billboard using a minimal area of plywood. The printed area must be $2000$ sq ft. Here are the margins:
side margins     $10$ ft
top margin   $8$ ft
bottom margin    $6$ ft.

How can I find the optimal, width, height, and total area?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to minimize area. Let's call the printed area of dimension $x\times y$ where

$x$:= width of printed area, 
$y$: = height of printed area.

$xy = 2000\tag{1 printed Area }$

Now, we have to compute the width of the *billboard* with side margins of 10 feet: $\;w = x + 2\cdot 10 = x + 20$

And the height of the *billboard* being: $\;y + 8 + 6 = y + 14$

We want to minimize the total area $A$ of the *billboard*, with $$\;A = (x+ 20)(y+ 14) = 14x + xy + 20y + 280\tag{Billboard Area}$$

Using $(1)$: $y = \dfrac {2000}{x}$

Substituting into the equation for the area of the billboard gives us $$A = 14x + 2000 + 20\cdot \frac{2000}x + 280 = 14x + \dfrac{40000}{x} + 2280\tag{A}$$

Now, find the derivative of $A$, $A'$ with respect to $x$, and set the resulting derivative equal to zero: The solution to that equation will give you the value of $x$ where any minimums and/or maximums are going to occur. You'll need to test each solution (if more than one positive solution exists) to see which is a minumum: which gives you the least possible value when $A$ is evaluated there.

Then you'll compute the value of $A$, total area, the value of $x + 20$, and the value of $y + 14$.

Feel free to check back once you've differentiated and found the solutions that solve $A' = 0$ (Hint: after derivating, you may want to multiply through by $x^2$ to simplify $A' = 0$, so it is more easily solvable.

Comment: width of plywood = W+ side margins =W+10
height of plywood =H+top margin+ bottom margin = H+8+6= H+14
Plywood area= (W+10)*(H+14) from equation no.1 W=2000/H
So plywood area =(2000/H +10)(H+14) 
=(2000+10H +28000/H+140)
so plywood area = 2140+10H+28000/H
So d(plywood area)/dH =0 ------>>>> 0=d(2140+10H+28000/H)/dH
So 0=0+10-28000/(H^2) ---->>>
H^2=2800 ----->>>> H=52.91 --->>> from equation no.1 W=2000/H=37.796
So height of plywood =H+14 =52.91+14=66.91 ft
And width of plywood =W+10 =37.796+10=47.796 ft

Comment: what are the correct answers because i feel this is incorrect

Comment: note that width of plywood = x + 10 + 10 = x + 20. (two side margins: left, right). $x$ is width of printed area, y is height of printed area, so height of plywood is $y + 14$. Plywood area is as stated above $A$. Try it with the correct area formula.

Comment: so whhat is the correct answer

Comment: i got 114 and 40

Comment: somewhere you went wrong because this still is incorrect values

Comment: please help me find correct values and i will give you the checkmark. i really would appreciate it

Comment: Therefore the correct answer would be?

Comment: oops, I factored incorrectly: you should get $14x^2 - 40000 = 0$ (I chopped off the 1 from the 14). Divide by 14: $x^2 - \dfrac {20000}{7}$: positive root will be $x = \sqrt{\dfrac 27}100$ and $ y = 20\sqrt{\dfrac 72}$ so width should be $\sqrt{\dfrac 27}100 + 20$, height should be $20\sqrt{\dfrac 72} + 14$

Comment: Thanks. You made me actually understand this. I appreciate what you have done. Regards

Comment: You're welcome, Michael. Sometimes it's more a matter of figuring out how to set the problem up than it is about calculus! ;-)

Comment: :-) ${}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: Hello, Babak! It is 2:00 a.m. for me...not a good evening for me (productivity/helpfulness), :-( but I am so sleepy, so I will probably go to bed very soon!